# Identifying which column in a dataframe has the highest value in python

Tags: python

I have a dataframe that's 11 columns by 17000 rows. I'm trying to identify the highest value in only three of the columns for each row. For instance, if my dataframe looks something like this:

| Country | Continent | Population M | Population F | Total Population |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| US | NA | 10M | 9M | 19M |
| China | Asia | 20M | 50M | 70M |
| UK | Europe | 75M | 10M | 85M |

I'd like to find out in each country, if there's a higher M or F population.

Comment: I can't test right now, so this might not work: `df['Dominant Sex'] = (df['Population M'] > df['Population F']).apply(lambda b: 'M' if b else 'F')`

Comment: @Clook did the answer below resolve your question ?

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way to do this by adding another column in your dataframe, based on result of conditional test ...

Note that this defaults to 'F´ in case of equality.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'country': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'm' : [1,2,3], 'f':[3,2,1]})

df['M_or_F'] = 'F'
df.loc[df['m'] > df['f'], 'M_or_F'] = 'M'

print(df)
```